# Spring batch with Empty reader gives exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Hi I am trying to write an Batch job which currently has only the processor, but I still need to write an empty reader and writer for later use.

```
@Component(BatchConstants.MY_BATCH_READER)
@StepScope
public class MyBatchReader implements ItemReader<String> {
    @Override
    public String read() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then referring this reader while building this job in another class

```
  @Autowired
    @Qualifier(BatchConstants.MY_BATCH_READER)
    MyBatchReader myBatchReader;
    
        Step step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstants.myBatchJob)
                .<String, String>chunk(1).reader(myBatchReader).processor(myProcessor)
                .writer(myWriter).build();
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstants.myBatchJob).start(step1)
                .build();
```

However when I tried this I got the below error -

.ItemReader is an interface. The implementing class will not be queried for annotation based listener configurations. If using @StepScope on a @Bean method, be sure to return the implementing class so listener annotations can be used.

and an **Exception MEthod threw BeanCreationException Cannot evaluate ..MyBatchReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87d9938.toString()**
I am new to springboot as well as spring batch, hence I am feeling there is some step I am certainly missing.

Also is it correct to use the same variable name for get method in Step and Job, I feel that is incorrect too.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Please add more details and paste the full stack trace of the error: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Autowired
    @Qualifier(BatchConstants.MY_BATCH_READER)
    MyBatchReader myBatchReader; This line when debugged gives the exception Method threw 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.batch.reader.MyBatchReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cc9f20ab.toString()

Comment: This is all that comes in the error, I checked my beans and they look fine is there  something wrong with the BatchReader implementation that has to internally do toString?

Comment: Why is the reader annotated with `@StepScope`? That does not add any value to the implementation you shared. This might be the cause of your issue.